# Drush Remote Alias Fails with No Drupal Site Found

Tags: drush

This is incredibly frustrating. Here's the deal. I have a drush alias defined for a server I'm working with. No matter what command it is, if it needs to bootstrap Drupal it fails with `no drupal site found` or some variant. Running `drush` with `--debug` gives me less than useful information although if you'd like to see it I'm happy to provide it.

I **can** run `drush @alias sqlc` and get the mysql command line on the remote server. I just cannot run things like `drush @alias st` or `drush @alias cc all` for example.

If I SSH to the server, change into the directory (i.e. `/sites/default`) and run the same commands they work fine. So this is only when going over a remote alias.

Here's the alias definition:

```
$aliases['alias'] = array(
     'uri' => 'site.com',
     'root' => '/usr/share/nginx/html/drupal/docroot',
     'remote-host' => 'us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
     'remote-user' => 'ubuntu',
     'ssh-options' => '-i /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa -q',
     'db-url' => 'mysql://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost/www',
     'path-aliases' => array(
       '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
       '%dump-dir' => '/tmp'
      ), 
      'command-specific' => array (
        'sql-sync' => array (
          'no-cache' => TRUE,
        ),
     ),
);
```

Am I missing something here? I've done this a thousand times and for whatever reason this time it refuses to work.

Note: I have downgraded to Drush 6.x just in case it was a 7.x problem. Same result.

Comment: Is your settings file in `sites/default/settings.php` on the remote? Or is it in a subdomain?

Comment: That's what's so odd. It's in the default folder. Everything works fine on the server.

Comment: Try removing the dburl from your aliases file. If that works I'll create an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that seems to fail. Here's what I get when I run `drush @myalias.www st`...

`Minmi:~ ksilanskas$ drush @myalias.www st
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  7.0.0
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing.... The problem was my `%root` directive. I had an additional directory tacked on. It was `usr/share/nginx/drupal/docroot`. Not no html in the path.

Upvotes for @Queenvictoria though for commenting and getting me to realize my error by poking back in the alias file. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found the solution. It had to be something simple!